# PowerPoint VBA Formatting

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a code that pulls other PowerPoint Slides into the end of a master file. This code has worked for months, and now it seems to mess up on formatting for a few pulls. The title comes in weird (eg. supposed to be blue and start from the left, coming in as black and centered). I checked all files and the source formatting is correct. Any help fixing this formatting issue would be appreciated.

```
Sub Wing()
Dim objPresentation As Presentation
Dim i As Integer
Dim intpresentation As Integer
Dim Max As Integer

'open the target presentation
Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open("\\nw\data\737MAX\12-Business_Ops\PP&C\14_IPTs\03_Airframe\01_IPT_Roll_Up\03_DBT\04_Winglet\737_MAX_Winglet_DBTC.pptx")

Max = objPresentation.Slides.Count

For i = 1 To Max

objPresentation.Slides.Item(i).Copy
        Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Item(Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Count).Design = _
        objPresentation.Slides.Item(i).Design
    Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Paste
Next i
objPresentation.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check your source, this happened to me once. Try to change the presentation to your desktop link it again, that way you can completely be sure it's not that.